# MongoDB: Strategy to remove / merge duplicate documents

Tags: mongodb, merge, duplicates

### Situation:

Let's consider we have a big application which contains an **Address Book** with contacts. And a huge part of the application saves references to those contacts.

### Problem:

Now the Address Book contains lot's of duplicate contacts (where `Contact A` and `Contact B` for example have the same `name` and `address` but different phone numbers, or one has a typing mistake within the name, etc.)

Both `Contact A` and `Contact B` were used within the application, though there are references for both of them saved in the DB. That's why we can't simply delete one of them and throw away its ID.

When a user now searches for a contact, he can't be sure which one is the right one to choose.

### Question:

What's the best / easiest / fastest solution, to handle this?

### Ideas:

1. **Basic and clean solution:** Merge the data: `Contact A -> Contact B`. Then update the whole database and replace everywhere `Contact A ID` with `Contact B ID`. Afterwards `Contact A` can be deleted safely. **But** this way may take a lot of time and you've got to write a lot of code.
2. **Two query solution:** Merge the data. Add a field `replaces` to `Contact B` which contains the ID of `Contact A`. Then delete `Contact A`. When there's a contact reference, the query it executes will look first for `_id = ...`, then for `replaces = ...`. If the second query succeeds, then we should update the reference with the right ID. **But** this way we need to create an additional Index.
3. **Two query solution reverse:** This is similar to **2.**: Merge the data. Add a field `replacedBy` to `Contact A`. When a query returns a contact that contains a `replacedBy` field, we must do another query to get the right contact and then replace the reference. **But** this way we will never delete `Contact A`, because we can't determine when all those references have been updated.
4. **Just hide the old/wrong entry:** Merge the data. And add some `deleted = true` field to the old/wrong contact. This way it won't appear in the address book. **But** the reference will still bring up the old/wrong data.

Ideally I'd use `_id` with an array of `ObjectId`s, **but** that's not supported by MongoDB as far as I know.

---

Please share your thoughts, pros and cons.

And maybe you've got another solution, that's event better / faster / more efficient / more elegant.

Comment: On what basis we can say that two contact is basically same person? because one person can have multiple phone numbers, more than one person can have same name and if the address is missing or partial. What is the determining factor that says Contact A and Contact B is basically duplicate?

Comment: The user decides what's the "same" person. And yes: One person can have multiple addresses, phone numbers, mail addresses, etc.. Here's a quite common example: User A get's some contact information for John Doe and creates a new entry for that contact, and then later User B get's also some other information for the same contact, but instead of updating the already existing one, he creates a second entry. Then we have 2 contacts for the same person. Of course it's a user fault, but I'm looking for a nice way to remove the duplicate. Data merging is **not** the problem, it's just all the DB refs